# Play Video 100% within the Div Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, video.js

How to make Youtube Video to be played 100% within the DIV Container.

Width of div  : 940px

Height of div : 400px

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gj9v2zrk/)**

```
<div class="videojs-wrapper">
    <div class="video-js-player">
        <video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay="autoplay" muted loop preload="auto" width="100%" height="400px" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/embed/5PaIjFd02js?enablejsapi=1" }'>
        </video>
    </div>

</div>


.video-content {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#aaa;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.videojs-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.video-js-play {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    right: 47%;
    left: 44%;
    width: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 36px;
}
.video-js-player {
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think you can do this:**

```
.video-js-player {
    position:relative;
    width:940px;
    height:400px;
}

.video-content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;//Change this to also 100%
    background:#f2f2f2;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#aaa;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```